# Debian: No authentication handler is configured to handle the scheme: Automatic

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, debian, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

I have some issue like [this](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/967), but i can't understand how to solve it for Debian.

At first, i configure my application as described below

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationScheme =MyAuthSchemeName,
                CookieName = MyCookiName,
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = false,
                SlidingExpiration = true,
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
                DataProtectionProvider = DataProtectionProvider.Create(MyApplicationName)
            });

app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            { 
                AutomaticChallenge = false,
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                Authority = IdentityServerConnectionString,
                RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
                BackchannelHttpHandler = new HttpClientHandler().ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (request, cert, chain, errors) => true,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                }
            });

app.UseMvc();
```

For windows it works perfectly (I use Host for launching this code, not IIS !), but for Debian it fails.
Any ideas?

**UPD:** I see next message in logs:  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware MyAuthSchemeName was not authenticated. Failure message: Unprotect ticket failed

Answer (score 2):

I found solution for this issue.
Key cause is a settings of DataProtectionProvider. 
For Debian it's needed to use code below

Startup.cs :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
      services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName(ApplicationName).
               PersistKeysToFileSystem(
                    new DirectoryInfo(Configuration["/some_path_to_folder_for_keys"]))
    }
```

And dataprovider initialization should be removed for cookie (from UseCookieAuthentication());