# "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" Angular and dotnet core WebApi using Docker

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core

I am trying to dockerize my Angular/WebApi application and with help from the community I have finally managed to build an image and being able to execute the image without errors in the console. But I am not able to navigate to my application using localhost.

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2.105 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY ["Fightplan_v1/Fightplan_v1.csproj", "Fightplan_v1/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate/Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate.Test/Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate.Test.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Autogenerate.Test/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Database/Fightplan_v1.Database.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Database/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Helpers/Fightplan_v1.Helpers.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Helpers/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Jobs/ConvertImagestoBlob/Fightplan_v1.ConvertImagestoBlob.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Jobs/ConvertImagestoBlob/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Models/Fightplan_v1.Models.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Models/"]
COPY ["Fightplan_v1.Shared/Fightplan_v1.Shared.csproj", "Fightplan_v1.Shared/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Fightplan_v1/Fightplan_v1.csproj"

# Setup NodeJs
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Fightplan_v1"
RUN dotnet build "Fightplan_v1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Fightplan_v1.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

# Build runtime image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Fightplan_v1.dll"]
```

Running `docker build -f .\fp.dockerfile -t test .` creates an image without any errors.
Running `docker run -p 5100:80 -it test` starts the image without any errors in the console:
[image] but it gives an `XmlKeyManager` warning:
[image]

When I try to go to `http://localhost:5100` I get a `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` in the browser and the console gives me this error:
[image]

I have tried to go directly to `172.17.0.1` instead of `localhost`. I have also tried to use `https` instead of `http` but that didn't give me the `unauthorized` error as above which should mean that hitting `http` is correct but the Angular application is not rendered.

Everything works locally without docker. I am able to publish the application via `dotnet` commands in powershell: `dotnet restore` and `dotnet publish`. This will make the application run on `https://localhost:5000`.

Am I missing another step in the Dockerfile?

Comment: Did you previously run this application locally on the same port? Try co clear all cookies for that domain in browser. This is related more to the IdentityServer configuration or/and angular app rather to the Docker, so to diagnose the problem some sources are required. This questions might be related: [Custom login UI for IdentityServer 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53030506/custom-login-ui-for-identityserver-4) and [Identity Server 4 Claims empty on API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50197603/identity-server-4-claims-empty-on-api)

Comment: Hi @Ivvan, thank you for your comment. I have tried to run it in incognito but that didn't help. Everything works fine locally without docker. I have updated my question. :)

Comment: This is definitely not a Docker problem anymore. Try to configure [DataProtection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44461281/2041039). It is still hard to recommend anything without actual code. Is your application need an authorization from the start? Check, if it redirects to correct login page (locally you are using https, so, if auth always redirect you to https, inside docker it will fails, because only http is configured). Also what king of auth you are using - cookie/jwt/other?

Comment: The root page and many other routes doesn't require login. I am using JWT. I will try changing the loca config of https to http and get back to you.

Comment: @Ivvan, this had something to do with a forced redirect. I posted the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was quite hidden but completely my own fault. I had a `app.UseHttpsRedirection()` in `Startup.cs`. I removed this and everything worked.